# Shopify ThemeKit - Need Help Deploying a Folder

Tags: terminal, shopify

I'm using Shopify's Debut theme and want to work locally. ThemeKit is installed and works perfectly when I run the command in terminal to "theme watch" to automatically update my theme files. A "fonts" folder with all its files was added locally and I would like to upload that. I turned off "theme watch" and ran this command "theme deploy --nodelete" and also tried this "theme deploy --nodelete fonts", but the folder isn't uploading. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add additional folders in the Shopify file structure.

I assume that you add it in the `assets` folder. There shouldn't be any folders there, only files.

Your file structure should like this:

```
- assets
- config
- layout
- locales
- sections
- snippets
- template
  - customers
```

No additional folders should be present in any of the above ones or outside of them.

Comment: I now see that it is impossible to add a folder. Thank you for your help.